# Protobuf-net Vs BinarySerializer Serialized List<T> Size

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I have started work with protobuf-net library. It increased speed of serialization on 30% but I have troubles with resulting file size.

My data model is:

```
    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
    private class ReportDataItem
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public Int32 C11 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public Int32 C12 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public Int32 C13 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public Int32 C14 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public Int32 C15 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(6)]
        public Int32 C16 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(7)]
        public Int32 C17 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(8)]
        public Int32 C18 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(9)]
        public Int32 C19 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(10)]
        public Int32 C110 { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(11)]
        public Int64 C21 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(12)]
        public Int64 C22 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(13)]
        public Int64 C23 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(14)]
        public Int64 C24 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(15)]
        public Int64 C25 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(16)]
        public Int64 C26 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(17)]
        public Int64 C27 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(18)]
        public Int64 C28 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(19)]
        public Int64 C29 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(20)]
        public Int64 C210 { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(21)]
        public String C31 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(22)]
        public String C32 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(23)]
        public String C33 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(24)]
        public String C34 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(25)]
        public String C35 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(26)]
        public String C36 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(27)]
        public String C37 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(28)]
        public String C38 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(29)]
        public String C39 { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(30)]
        public String C310 { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract()]
    private class ReportData
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
        public List<ReportDataItem> ReportDataItems { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [ProtoContract()]
    private class Report
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public ReportData ReportData { get; set; }
    }
```

So when I try to serialize:

```
    private static void ObjectSerialization()
    {
```

const string someData = @"qtwretyfsjdabvfsjdlfudspogds;kfg;lkfdsl;gkl;dsfkgl;kdfsgr;iweprpo\z\xlvcfmxzcbvjiorsdifdlf\jl;dsa";

```
            Report report = new Report();
            report.ReportData = new ReportData {ReportDataItems = new List<ReportDataItem>()};

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                ReportDataItem reportDataItem = new ReportDataItem();

                reportDataItem.C11 = j;
                reportDataItem.C12 = j;
                reportDataItem.C13 = j;
                reportDataItem.C14 = j;
                reportDataItem.C15 = j;
                reportDataItem.C16 = j;
                reportDataItem.C17 = j;
                reportDataItem.C18 = j;
                reportDataItem.C19 = j;
                reportDataItem.C110 = j;

                reportDataItem.C21 = j;
                reportDataItem.C22 = j;
                reportDataItem.C23 = j;
                reportDataItem.C24 = j;
                reportDataItem.C25 = j;
                reportDataItem.C26 = j;
                reportDataItem.C27 = j;
                reportDataItem.C28 = j;
                reportDataItem.C29 = j;
                reportDataItem.C210 = j;

                reportDataItem.C31 =someData;
                reportDataItem.C32 = someData;
                reportDataItem.C33 = someData;
                reportDataItem.C34 = someData;
                reportDataItem.C35 = someData;
                reportDataItem.C36 = someData;
                reportDataItem.C37 = someData;
                reportDataItem.C38 = someData;
                reportDataItem.C39 = someData;
                reportDataItem.C310 = someData;

                report.ReportData.ReportDataItems.Add(reportDataItem);
            }

            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\Test\Object\0.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, report);
            }

            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\Test\Object\bf_0.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream, report);
            }
}
```

I had results provided below:

- ***protobuf-net** file size **10428 Bytes***
- ***BinaryFormatter** file size **3458 Bytes***

Could you help me to find a right solution for decrease a size of result protobuf-net file.
Protobuf-net I installed as a package from VS Package Manager.

Comment: What about running it though a compression stream? Oh and using such repetitive values doesn't look like a representative test to me.

Comment: I've just run your test, and I get 1628 bytes from protobuf-net; please verify

Comment: The main idea that standard .NET BinaryFormatter without compression works slower but as a result have smaller file than protobuf-net library . I look for solution how to improve code by features from protobuf-net library. Maybe some attribute or other feature. The execution speed is very important for me. This is one of the reasons why I try to use protobuf-net.

Comment: @Puh I *think* I know what is going on - your actual test uses a longer string than "some data", right? See the update to my answer.

Comment: @Marc Gravell Yes, thank you for this comment. You are right. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Puh if the real data isn't going to have the same string over and over, I strongly suggest trying the same test with different strings in each instance; you might be surprised what BF grows to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the last few lines to:

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"pb.bin", FileMode.Create,
     FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, report);
    Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
}
Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo("pb.bin").Length);

using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"bf.bin", FileMode.Create,
     FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, report);
    Console.WriteLine(stream.Length);
}
Console.WriteLine(new FileInfo("bf.bin").Length);
```

to get the amount of data written to the stream, and the final size of the files. My results:

```
1628
1628
3144
3144
```

Which looks fine to me. Please verify your data.

Is it possible that you are using a much bigger string than "some data"? If so, there is an important question: are you likely to be duplicating the strings in real code? If you aren't, then the BF test is invalid, because it will be using *reference tracking* by default, so only storing the strings once - but your real data will behave very differently. If you ***are*** going to be using the same string lots of times, then you can mimic this re-use in protobuf-net:

```
[ProtoMember(21, AsReference=true)]
public String C31 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(22, AsReference = true)]
public String C32 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(23, AsReference = true)]
public String C33 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(24, AsReference = true)]
public String C34 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(25, AsReference = true)]
public String C35 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(26, AsReference = true)]
public String C36 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(27, AsReference = true)]
public String C37 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(28, AsReference = true)]
public String C38 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(29, AsReference = true)]
public String C39 { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(30, AsReference = true)]
public String C310 { get; set; }
```

The output now:

```
939
939
3144
3144
```

However! This will slightly grow the output if the strings are *not* generally repeated, and will make it hard for other protobuf implementations to use it (it is valid protobuf data, but via some voodoo).

The above is useful if, for example, you have things like custom names / country names / statuses etc that are represented as strings but duplicated lots.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is really help me! [ProtoMember(30, **AsReference = true**)]
public String C310 { get; set; }

Comment: @Puh again, that will only help if the values are likely to be repeated.